# Any way to make service do not autostart in Ubuntu/Debian, but leave K00 scripts in place?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, init, runlevel

I need to have only stop scripts in rcN.d (runlevels 0,1,6) for apache2.
So that I always start it by myself, but when reboot occurs server will shut down apache2 properly.
**And** when I change runlevel 2-3 server doesnt' touch apache daemon (leaving it in the state it is).

Basically, I just need a legal way to remove apache2 startup symlinks from rc2.d -> rc5.d. With tools like update-rc.d.

I can just remove those symlinks by hands, but I'm not sure if this is a proper way for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove symblinks by hands, there is no problem to do that this way if you know what you are doing.

Comment: And the next time the service's package is updated update-rc.d is run again and the links are recreated...

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick :

```
update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

Basically `update-rc.d` will modify existing runlevel links for the script `/etc/init.d/apache2` by renaming start links to stop links.

If you wanted to disable only runlevel 2 and 5, you could do :

```
update-rc.d apache2 disable 2 5
```

nico

Comment: I do not what runlevels 2,3,4,5 to affect apache2 at all. 
In you case apache2 will be stopped, if it was running.

Comment: No it wouldn't be stopped :-) When you reboot your server, you're switching it from runlevel 2 (Debian's default) to runlevel 6 and that's when all the scripts in `/etc/rc6.d/` are executed. Since you're already in runlevel 2 when executing the command, nothing will happen to the Apache2 processes.

Comment: But what if i switch to runlevel 3, 4 or 5? It would stop. That is the reason.

Answer (score 6):

```
sysv-rc-conf
```

is the new way to do this job.

[image]

Comment: Amazing tool! In official repos & also provides arguments for easy one liners like `sysv-rc-conf --display apache2` and `sysv-rc-conf apache2 off`

Answer (score 2):

```
update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

Comment: This also removes shutdown scripts, which I want to leave (for reboot/halt).